# Installation Issues with ruby and gem rdiscount windows 8 64bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll, rdiscount

I am attempting to get Jekyll and bower working within Windows 8

I have managed to install Ruby, and the DevKit, 
I tried, version 2.0.2, 1.9.3 and then again with the Rails installer from http://railsinstaller.org/

I have followed both scenario A and B at the following, https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun but neither are relevant to me,

COMSPEC is my cmd.exe location and I don't have an autorun?

I can run `gem install mysql` but attempting to do either rdiscount gives the following

```
c:\devkit>gem install rdiscount
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for random()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
    --with-rdiscount-dir
    --without-rdiscount-dir
    --with-rdiscount-include
    --without-rdiscount-include=${rdiscount-dir}/include
    --with-rdiscount-lib
    --without-rdiscount-lib=${rdiscount-dir}/lib
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler
failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link 0'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:894:in `block in have_func'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:893:in `have_fun c'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

If I run `gem install jekyll` I get the following error

```
porter.c:238:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier from  pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:240:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *' porter.c:240:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'setto' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:196:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:241:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:241:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'setto' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:196:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:242:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:242:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'setto' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:196:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:249:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'setto' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:196:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c: In function 'step1c':
porter.c:257:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c: In function 'step2':
porter.c:267:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:267:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:268:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:268:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:270:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:270:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:271:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:271:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:273:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:273:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:275:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:275:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:280:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:280:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:281:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:281:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:282:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:282:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:283:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:283:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:285:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:285:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:286:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:286:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:287:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:287:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:289:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:289:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:290:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:290:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:291:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:291:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:292:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:292:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:294:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:294:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:295:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:295:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:296:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:296:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:298:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:298:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c: In function 'step3':
porter.c:308:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:308:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:309:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:309:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:310:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:310:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:312:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:312:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:314:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:314:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:315:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:315:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier f
rom pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:317:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:317:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'r' discards 'const' qualifier fr
om pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:205:13: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c: In function 'step4':
porter.c:325:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:326:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:327:17: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:328:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:329:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:330:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:331:17: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:332:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:333:17: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:334:17: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:335:17: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:336:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:337:17: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:339:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:340:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:341:17: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifie
r from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:342:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:343:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:344:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
compiling porter_wrap.c
In file included from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h
:1376:0,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from porter_wrap.c:1:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:41:8: error: redef
inition of 'struct timespec'
In file included from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../.
./../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.
h:62,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/define
s.h:223,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h
:67,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from porter_wrap.c:1:
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw
32/include/sys/types.h:89:8: note: originally defined here
In file included from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h
:1376:0,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from porter_wrap.c:1:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:48:8: error: redef
inition of 'struct timezone'
In file included from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.
h:63:0,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/define
s.h:223,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h
:67,
                 from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from porter_wrap.c:1:
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw
32/include/time.h:260:8: note: originally defined here
make: *** [porter_wrap.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stem
mer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out

c:\devkit>
```

I have also tried reinstalling/updating gem but nothing I have followed seem to work?

can anyone think of anything else I can try? or point me to somewhere that can help.

This is my first attempt at Ruby and I am not having much luck.

Thanks
Sean

Comment: Did you execute `ruby dk.rb install` to actually install the devkit after you unpacked it?

Comment: Yes, first ruby dk.rb init then 
ruby dk.rb install

and then ruby dk.rb install -f (when I moved the install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue fixed with rdiscount 2.0.7.2

```
gem install rdiscount -v 2.0.7.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't Ruby, RubyInstaller or DevKit, but RDiscount gem broken on Windows, see reported [issue #74](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/issues/74).

You can install an older version of RDiscount, like 1.6.x:

```
gem install rdiscount -v 1.6.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the link glad to know that my ruby installation was fruitful.

I have attempted to use the previous version you mention but get the same error. Looks like I need to hold fire on this or work on the vagrantup set up correctly.

Comment: If you can install other gems like json or RedCloth, then I suggest you post this to RubyInstaller group. Sometimes a mismatch of Ruby/DevKit can cause weird errors.